# What is the proper Pythonic Approach to Collection.forEach?

Tags: python, list

I inevitably end up writing a lot of functions that look something along the lines of

```py
def forEach(function: typing.Callable, collection: typing.Iterable) -> typing.NoReturn:
    for item in collection:
        function(item)
```

Just about every language I've worked in has had some form of `forEach` function, whether it's [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in Javascript, [Iterable.forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) in Java, or [List.forEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-8.0) in C#. Python lists don't have that. I've talked with some people and we've hashed out stuff like `any(function(item) for item in collection)` or `[function(item) for item in collection]`, but stuff that looks like it should work, like `map(function, collection)`, doesn't do anything until iterated upon.

Now, I'm sure there's 18 billion pip packages that may be used, but is there a more elegant/pythonic way to do this in vanilla? My example above does the trick, but it still seems odd that I have to either write a function like this or write out the loop every time this would get called.

Comment: Unless it's doing more than just calling the function on each element of the iterable, the loop itself is the Pythonic way to do this. `forEach(f, foo)` isn't that much shorter than `for _ in foo: f(_)`, and adds the overhead (slight as it may be) of a function call.

Comment: You can use `map(function, iterable)` and ignore the return value

Comment: The recipes section of the `itertools` documentation provides a definition of `consume`, which you would use as `consume(map(f, foo))`; the `more-itertools` package includes it.

Comment: The only thing unpythonic about your solution is writing a function to do it; a short two line piece of code is easy to write and easy to understand.

Comment: From the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/): `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.` In this case that's a `for in` loop.

Comment: @Barmar `map` returns an iterator which, if no iteration happens, does nothing (including not calling the `function`).

Comment: Minor point: `typing.NoReturn` is for functions that do not return normally (because they have an infinite loop or always raise an exception). Your function is more properly annotated as `def forEach[T](function: Callable[[T], Any], collection: Iterable[T]) -> None:`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yeah, forgot about that. Which is why I upvoted chepner's `consume()` recommendation.

Comment: In Python 2, `map` would have been *an* answer, though still frowned upon for creating a list that would be immediately discarded.

Comment: The pythonic thing is simply to use a for-loop if you are using a function for side-effects. There is nothing odd ab out a for-loop. For loops are *very pythonic*. If your functions is a pure function, then use a list comprehension (or similar construct) or `map` (or even just a for-loop)

Comment: Summed up the consensus in the answer, thanks for the input. And @Jasmijn, the wonky type hints are just because I was trying to save up on horizontal space and make it obvious nothing was gonna be returned - you're not gonna see me writing stuff that goofy :D
I hadn't considered `-> None:`, though. I usually just leave that off. I'm gonna use that in examples from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested in the future, general consensus is KISS - a simple for-loop is enough, no reason to dip into the world of collection owned `forEach` functions.

Creating a function to perform the loop upon the collection adds unnecessary overhead, as small as it is.

Coming from another language, say Javascript, the following may feel natural:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'].forEach(console.log)
```

But you may as well just spell it out in Python:

```
for word in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
    print(word)
```

Instead of something like:

```
forEach(print, ['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

The one-liner doesn't add a whole lot and devs who spend more time in python than in other languages might double-take over it upon first glance.

**TL;DR**

If you're putting thought into this, you've thought too much about it.